# Movement keys stop moving though key hasn't been released

Tags: javascript, replit

It was hard to properly summarize the problem I am facing. I am making a random game to try and learn js and I have run into a problem which affects the player movement badly.

I am coding on repl.it as it is easier for me so here is the link to the code so here is the link to the project https://repl.it/@PeterChaplin_Sm/Epic-game go onto script.js if it wasn't obvious enough:

```js
//canvasy boi
function setup() {
 createCanvas(500, 400);
}

// rectangular boi records
var rect1 = {x: 5, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50, xspeed: 0, yspeed: 0}
var rect2 = {x: 20, y: 10, width: 50, height: 50, xspeed: 0, yspeed: 5}
var rect3 = {x: 90, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50, xspeed: 0, yspeed: 6}

function draw() {
 background(200);
 
  //rectangular bois
 fill(255, 0, 0);
 rect(rect1.x, rect1.y, rect1.width, rect1.height);

  fill(0, 0, 255);
 rect(rect2.x, rect2.y, rect2.width, rect2.height);
  
  fill(0, 0, 255);
 rect(rect3.x, rect3.y, rect3.width, rect3.height);
  //player movement
 if(rect1.x >= 0 && rect1.x + 50 <= 500) rect1.x += rect1.xspeed;
 if(rect1.y >= 0 && rect1.y + 50 <= 500) rect1.y += rect1.yspeed;
  //asteroids
  if(rect2.x >= 0 && rect2.x + 50 <= 500) rect2.x += rect2.xspeed;
 if(rect2.y >= 0 && rect2.y + 50 <= 500) rect2.y += rect2.yspeed;

  if(rect3.x >= 0 && rect3.x + 50 <= 500) rect3.x += rect3.xspeed;
 if(rect3.y >= 0 && rect3.y + 50 <= 500) rect3.y += rect3.yspeed;

  //JUST MAKE SURE THE FREAKIN RED THING DOESNT GO OUT OF THE FREAKIN BOX
  if(rect1.y <= 0) rect1.y = rect1.y+1;
  if(rect1.x <= 0) rect1.x = rect1.x+1; 
  if(rect1.y >= 350) rect1.y = rect1.y-5;
  if(rect1.x >= 450) rect1.x = rect1.x-1;

  //makes things fall woah
  if(rect2.y >= 400) rect2.y = -50;
  if(rect2.y < 0) rect2.y = rect2.y+rect2.yspeed;

  if(rect3.y >= 400) rect3.y = -50;
  if(rect3.y < 0) rect3.y = rect3.y+rect3.yspeed;

  if (rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width &&
   rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x &&
   rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height &&
   rect1.y + rect1.height > rect2.y) {
     text("Hit!", 250, 25)
  }

  if (rect1.x < rect3.x + rect3.width &&
   rect1.x + rect1.width > rect3.x &&
   rect1.y < rect3.y + rect3.height &&
   rect1.y + rect1.height > rect3.y) {
     text("Hit!", 250, 25)
  }
  
  fill(255,0,0)
  text(rect1.x, 25, 50)
  text(rect1.y, 25, 75)
  fill(0,0,255)
  text(rect2.x, 50, 50)
  text(rect2.y, 50, 75)


  //if(xpos >= cxpos && xpos <= cxpos+50 && ypos >= cypos && ypos <= cypos+50 || xpos+50 >= cxpos && xpos+50 <= cxpos+50 && ypos+50 >= cypos && ypos+50 <= cypos+50) text("DEAD", 25, 100) ;

  //if(deaths >= 1) text("you died you bad person lol", 25, 100), cyspeed=0; 
}

//keypresses
function keyPressed() {
 switch(keyCode) {
  case 37:
  case 65:
   rect1.xspeed = -4;
   break;
  case 39:
  case 68:
   rect1.xspeed = 4;
   break;
  case 38:
  case 87:
   rect1.yspeed = -4;
   break;
  case 40:
  case 83:
   rect1.yspeed = 4;
   break;
 }
}

//keyreleases
function keyReleased() {
 switch(keyCode) {
  case 37:
  case 65:
   rect1.xspeed = 0;
   break;
  case 39:
  case 68:
   rect1.xspeed = 0;
   break;
  case 38:
  case 87:
   rect1.yspeed = 0;
   break;
  case 40:
  case 83:
   rect1.yspeed = 0;
   break;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

If you run the game and then hold down the D key and then press A then release A, the character doesn't move to the left even though the D key is still pressed and I don't know how to implement something that fixes this, any help appreciated.

If anyone needs any more information about it comment what you need below.

Comment: I rate your comments in your code :P The issue is that when you assign a velocity on key pressed and let go, you are not reassigning the velocity of the key you are already holding down.

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this would be like so (pseudo)

- onkeydown (movement keys only) add key to the end of an array
- onkeyup (movement keys only) remove key from array
- if movement keys array length > 0, use the last element's value for movement

Using this method you would also be able to implement diagonal movement if you wanted.

Comment: Diagonal movement already works but i will try use something like that thanks :)